# JPA @OneToMany update error

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities-

```
@Entity
public class PriceList extends Model {
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "price_list_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "price_list_item_id")},
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"price_list_id", "price_list_item_id"})}
)
private Set<PriceListItem> priceListItems = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
public class PriceListItem extends Model {
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   private Task task;
   private double price;
}
```

When I try to add a new `PriceListItem` to the list (the price list were already persisted), and try to update, I get below given error -

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`track`.`price_list_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK19qdwn6vfsjxdxl7355ojo39l` FOREIGN KEY (`task_id`) REFERENCES `task` (`id`))

The code I am using to update is -

```
 public PriceList updatePriceList(final PriceList priceList) throws PriceListNotFoundException {
    final PriceListItem priceListItem = createPriceListItem(task, price);
    priceList.getPriceListItems().add(priceListItem);
    return priceListDao.save(priceList);
}
```

Anyone knows why I am getting this error? I am using latest Hibernate with latest Spring Data JPA.

Comment: The problem seems to be with your `PriceListItem` and `Task` relation. What are you passing to `createPriceListItem` method? Was the `task` object already persisted one?

Comment: Try removing the `uniqueConstraints` property of the `@JoinTable`

Comment: @Dark yes the `task` object was already persisted. And on `PriceListItem` the `task` is annotated with `@ManyToOne`. And there is no cascade type declared.

Comment: @NeilStockton I thought hibernate users could give some comment as well.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan I have tried removing the constraint, but still the same.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan After removing the constraint the error is now -

`a foreign key constraint fails (`track`.`price_list_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK19qdwn6vfsjxdxl7355ojo39l` FOREIGN KEY (`task_id`) REFERENCES `task` (`id`))`